# table cell and break word doesnt work

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list with some LI's inside, the LI's are set to display: table-cell - However, when doing this then it doesn't break long words - I've tried setting the word-wrap-break-word; and table-layout: fixed, but it doesn't work...
[You can see the problem here](http://test.de.rmig-express.dkis.dk/express-tafeln/iso/lochbleche-und-streckmetalle.aspx?SortBy=&SortOrder=&ProductGroup=&SearchMaterial=&SheetThickness=&SheetSizeWidth=&SheetSizeLength=&HoleTypeISO=&HoleSize=&PitchTypeISO=&PitchSize=&OpenArea=0-55&freesearchText=) - look at how the columns doesn't align, because of long words...

Comment: You really should reconsider the design there, especially the numbers breaking in the "Größe" column, the long German words broken at wrong places and the long texts in the "Lieferung" and "Preis" columns makes that table unreadable. AND: That's obliviously a data-table so you should be using a HTML table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mention `word-break: break-all` style in li

```
ul.dis-product-list-line li {
    display: table-cell;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a table instead? They allow you to arrange data...
I think that's a better and proper solution to your problem.

Comment: Im new to Stackoverflow, how do I do that? It seems that i'm only able to comment my own posts/answers.

Comment: Unfortunately as a newbie, you'll have to refrain from commenting (especially using an answer) until you've collected enough reputation. But don't worry, you only need 50 for that.